# Accessing Cookies from static class in ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies

I'm Trying to access Cookies from Static Class in Asp.net Core , So far I couldn't find any useful topics on Google. any Suggestions?

I already Did that in asp.net:

```
public static string GetString(string Key)
        {
            var format = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Language"];
            if (format == null)
                format = new HttpCookie("Language") { Value = "Fa" };
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Ippv.Virtual.Application.Properties." + format.Value,
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            return rm.GetString(Key);
        }
```

How can I write equivalent of this code in asp.net core?

Comment: Showing some relevant code would help. Why can't you pass the cookie value as a parameter to the static method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET, we can access cookies using httpcontext.current but in ASP.NET Core, there is no htttpcontext.currently. In ASP.NET Core, everything is decoupled and modular.Httpcontext is accessible from Request object and the IHttpContextAccessor interface which is under "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" namespace and this is available anywhere in the application. Refer to the following code:

```
 public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public TestController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        public  IActionResult Index()
        {
 //read cookie from IHttpContextAccessor  
            string cookieValueFromContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["key"];
            //read cookie from Request object  
            string cookieValueFromReq = Request.Cookies["Key"];
            //set the key value in Cookie  
            Set("kay", "Hello from cookie", 10);
            //Delete the cookie object  
            Remove("Key");
            return View();
        }
        /// <summary>  
        /// Get the cookie  
        /// </summary>  
        /// <param name="key">Key </param>  
        /// <returns>string value</returns>  
        public string Get(string key)
        {
            return Request.Cookies[key];
        }
        /// <summary>  
        /// set the cookie  
        /// </summary>  
        /// <param name="key">key (unique indentifier)</param>  
        /// <param name="value">value to store in cookie object</param>  
        /// <param name="expireTime">expiration time</param>  
        public void Set(string key, string value, int? expireTime)
        {
            CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
            if (expireTime.HasValue)
                option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expireTime.Value);
            else
                option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(10);
            Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, option);
        }
        /// <summary>  
        /// Delete the key  
        /// </summary>  
        /// <param name="key">Key</param>  
        public void Remove(string key)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Delete(key);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this was written a long time ago, but I had the same issue and couldn't find the answer,

There is an nuget package that adds the functionality you are looking for. The link is:

[GitHub project repository](https://github.com/dotnet/systemweb-adapters/tree/main)

The instructions are in the page but in short, by adding this package and adding to lines to your program.cs file you can access the cookies and all other data in the Context via static methods.

Add the package: **Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters**

Below is example code of it working. The cookie needs to exist or the code will error but I think you can see the logic

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// Added to enable SystemWeb
builder.Services.AddSystemWebAdapters();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

// Added to enable SystemWeb
app.UseSystemWebAdapters();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

My static class

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public static class Test
    {
        public static void Run() {

            string value = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Value;
            Debug.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("MyCookie", "Value1");

            Test.Run();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```